# Access `this` of a class from an object within the class in javascript

Tags: javascript

The code structre is quite simple:

```
class A {
    b = 1
    c = {
        d () {
            console.log(this.b) //=> undefined
            //how can i access b here?
        }
    }
}
```

I would prefer a not so hacky workaround since this is a core piece of code for the project i am working on

Comment: What is d? It looks like you mean for d to be a function. In which case, you should write **function d() {}** (or **d: function() {}** within your c object) rather than **d() {}**. Arrow notation is a compact and more limited version of function.

Comment: @Euthyphro [shorthand function notations in objects have been a feature in js since ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#method_definitions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve `this` where the function is being declared:

```js
class A {
    b = 1
    c = {
        d: () => console.log(this.b)
    }
}

const a = new A;
a.c.d();
```